# Is there any advance setting in TortoiseSVN to keep the changelist by default

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Based on TortoiseSVN documentation for [changelist](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-changelists.html),

> If you wish to retain the file in its changelist, use the Keep
>   changelists checkbox at the bottom of the commit dialog.

I was wondering if there is an existing flag in Tortoise advance settings to check that options automatically.

I would like to keep all my created list after every commit, which this option (checkbox) works perfectly. But in case I forgot to check it, I don't want to recreate them again.

Comment: It is possible that this could be a hidden flag in the CLI for TortoiseProc.exe (https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html), but I guess the tortoisesvn maintainers don't check SO, so you would have to ask them directly